# How to shrink the imageView on hide in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am having an imageView and a label side by side. I want to remove width and height of the image when it's hidden. Yes we can do it programmatically by setting the height and width constraints to 0, but is it any other way by storyboard. I have placed imageView inside horizontal stackView without width constraints but it is working just opposite, increasing it's width on hiding the imageView.

Comment: What you've described doesn't make much sense... *"I have placed imageView inside horizontal stackView without width constraints..."* -- do you have width constraints on the stackView? Have you changed content hugging priority on either the image view or the label (from the defaults)? What have you set for the alignment / distribution / spacing of the stackView?

Answer (score -1):

How about use another UI for shrinking ImageView

for example

**AS IS**

UIStackView with arranged UILabel, UIImageView, UILabel, UIView(isHidden true)

when you need to shrink UIImageView with hidden then make hidden UIImageView and make shown UIView.

It makes UIImageView width 0 like because UIView should be expanded full size (hugging priority less)

**TO BE**

UIStackview with UILabel, UILabel, stretched UIView(low hugging priority and isHidden false)